# Setting a color for a checkbox label

Tags: jquery, checkbox, colors, label

I want to do the above subject matter for the phrase "Include items above during check out". When I debug via Firebug, the correct lines in the script are getting hit, but the color never changes.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

**HTML**

```
<td colspan="7" valign="middle" align="left" class="underline" style="line-height: 20px;padding: 0; color: #fff;">
    <span class="eg_checkbox" style="font-weight:bold;">
        <input id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$datalistDTO$ctl01$chkShiptoSubmit" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$datalistDTO$ctl01$chkShiptoSubmit\',\'\')', 0)"/>
        <label for="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit">Include items above during check out</label>
    </span>
</td>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit').is(':checked')) {
        $('label[for=#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit]').css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $('label[for=#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit]').css('color', 'blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: Something happened with your indenting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'for' selector is wrong in your jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit').is(':checked')) {
        $('label[for="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit"]').css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $('label[for="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit"]').css('color', 'blue');
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/zAVG5/)

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `#` sign in your attribute selector and instead of selecting the elements multiple times you can cache the selector and use `next()` method which selects the next element. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $checkbox = $('#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit'); 
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        $checkbox.next('label').css('color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $checkbox.next('label').css('color', 'blue');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fCc9C/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It was your `#`. Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/EtZYt/17/)

Notice the `for=ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/NbVUm/

html:

```
<table><tr>
<td colspan="7" valign="middle" align="left" class="underline"
    style="line-height: 20px; padding: 0; color: #fff;">
  <span class="eg_checkbox" style="font-weight:bold;">
    <input id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit"
      type="checkbox"
      name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceHolder$datalistDTO$ctl01$chkShiptoSubmit"
      checked="checked" />
    <label for="ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_datalistDTO_ctl01_chkShiptoSubmit">
      Include items above during check out
    </label>
  </span>
</td>

</tr></table>
```

js:

```
$(function()
{
  var cb = $(':checkbox');
  cb.change(on_cb_changed);

  on_cb_changed();

  function on_cb_changed()
  {
    var label = cb.next('label');

    label.css('color', cb.is(':checked') ? 'red' : 'blue');
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I removed the onclick handler from the html